# Executing console command in R

Tags: r

I would like to execute this DOS command under R:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 FileName.md > FileNameNew.md
```

The above command creates new file after transforming from ISO to UTF.

I have tried execute this command however unsuccessfully with:

```
system(paste("iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 FileName.md > FileNameNew.md", sep=""))
```

This gives me two types of errors:

```
Invalid argument
No such file or directory
```

I don't think the issue is the second since when I run the command under R it in fact executes the command as it re-reads the `FileName.md`, which means he found the file. I think it is just a issue with the `>` and hence formulation of the command in the `system(paste(""))` command.

When I rund this command directly under console it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (most likely) simply with where the R session is located. Check this by running `getwd()` in R and see if it is in the same place as the file. The paste part shouldn't be needed, as it is not really pasting anything (paste combines 2 strings together, while it is one string here).

Solve this by explicitly attaching input and output to those files.

If you would insist on using paste, you could use it for instance like this:

```
system(paste("iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 ", getwd(), "/FileName.md > ", 
                                              getwd(), "/FileNameNew.md", sep=""))
```

Comment: The path is fine. I set the path with setwd().

Comment: Try escaping the "<" perhaps? "\<", though I doubt that'll be it.

Comment: In your command should be included "/" as this...getwd(), "/FileName.md

Comment: But still doesn't work. The path seems fine. It is the ">" I believe.